# Why VS2008 debugging stops after one page cycle?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7, windows-vista

I would really appreciate some thoughts on the following issue.

When I attached to the `w3wp.exe` process.

- It starts to load the symbols.
- Then the debugger stops before ever hitting a breakpoint.

If I restart the  `w3wp` process and refresh “Attach to process” I can debug but only one page cycle.

- I have reinstalled IIS7 on Vista.
- I updated VS2008 with Service Pack 1.

I would like to know why debugging stops after one page cycle. This happens with all of my projects.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in the web.config file for your web site?

Comment: yeah, i've done thats. To clarify i can reach a breakpoint but then once the page cycle ends then the debugging stops.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old question. However, for the record, you also want to make sure that VS is running with admin privileges. This could also cause what you were experiencing.

Comment: thanks, this could have been the issue. Was many years ago now and now  have new machine and vs version. But your answer could be correct.